# Google Play Game Services + BaseGameUtils: Automated sign-in in second Activity?

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my game's main menu, I offer the user the possibility to sign in via Google+ (using the Google Play Games Services based on the TypeANumber-sample). This works fine. The user then plays the game, and is directed to my "End Round"-screen, which is another activity. In this activity, I'd like to save the user's score to Google Play Games Services, but `isSignedIn()`returns false. What is the recommended approach to re-establish a connection to Google Play Games Services in this new activity? The BaseGameUtils-Library doesn't offer a "SilentReconnect"-Method.

My first idea would be updating a boolean `usesGooglePlus`-variable in the local app settings once the user signs in/out on the main activity, and then calling `beginUserInitiatedSignIn();` in my EndRound-activity (if `usesGooglePlus` is true), but this doesn't sound "right". Is there a better way to re-establish the connection/get the GamesClient?

Thanks!
[image: sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) and it seems that the EndRound-activity should also extend `BaseGameActivity` so that the connection is automatically established in `onStart()` and the score can then be submitted after `onSignInSucceeded()` has been called.

Comment: Hi thiagolr, thanks for your comment. There is a compulsory waiting time before you can accept your own answer, which isn't over yet.