# Google Play Game Services - cannot submit score on next activity

Tags: android, google-play-services

Following are two activities implemented using BaseGameUtils Library and google play services library [for actual question go to end of this code].
  This is Activity A

```
        import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;

        public class A extends BaseGameActivity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
            }
        //button to start play managed from layout
            public void startPlay(View view) {

                startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
            }


    // from layout i m managing signin onclick
            public void signInControl(View view) {

                beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        // from layout i m managing signout onclick
            public void signOutControl(View view) {

                signOut();

                // show sign-in button, hide the sign-out button
                findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSignInFailed() {

                findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSignInSucceeded() {
                findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        }
```

Now my next Activity B

```
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;

public class B extends BaseGameActivity {
    int MY_SCORE = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        subMitScore();//

    }

    private void subMitScore() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (isSignedIn()) {

            getGamesClient().submitScore(
                    getString(R.string.leaderboard_total_scores), MY_SCORE);
        } else {
            Log.d("not signed", "Not signed in");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("sigin failed", "inside on onSignInFailed");

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("sigin succeded", "inside on onSignInSucceeded");
    }

}
```

using above code can successfully login to google game centre at Activity A which is a BaseGameActivity and i need to submit my score at Activity B which is also a BaseGameActivity ,but inside activity B i always get isSignedIn() as false so the submitscore code is never called so my exact question is how do i submit my game score from Activity B ,as my game ends at activity B and i get my total score at B.

Note:Tried solutions from--[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962210/google-play-game-services-not-signed-in-on-next-activity/21962414?noredirect=1#comment33451976_21962414) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742341/google-play-game-services-basegameutils-automated-sign-in-in-second-activity?rq=1) but didnt get any results.

**

> 

### EDIT

**

just edited activity B code

called subMitScore() method inside onSignInsucceeded()

like

```
@Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            submitScore()


    }
```

Previously my onSignInSucceeded() was not getting called [dont know exactly why] but above thing solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're submitting the score in the Activity onCreate method. At that point in the Activity life cycle the Google Play Game Services client is not connected, it will connected only later. Try submitting the score later (for example in the onSignInSucceeded method).

In general, it's probably not a good idea to submit scores this way. Submit the score after the game is over, during the normal game play & activity run time.

Comment: thanks for reply but onSignInSucceeded is never getting called as you can see i've checked for log in onSignInSucceeded method.

Comment: Is that the entire Activity B code? the most common reason for onSignInSucceeded not to be called is overriding onActivityResult without calling super.onActivityResult in the method body.

Comment: have put an edited answer tried according to your suggesstion.